# Applying a row template to a grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I was trying to apply a row template to a grid, but the data is not shown... 
I'm begining with a very simple template, after I will customize it.

What I have so far:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Models.StudentCF>().
Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Age);
    columns.Bound(p => p.Course);
    columns.Bound(p => p.School.Name);
})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("IndexJsonCF", "StudentCF"))
)
.Selectable()
.AutoBind(true)
.Filterable()
.Groupable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable(pager =>
{
    pager.Input(true);
    pager.Messages(messages => messages.Display("Showing items from {0} to {1}. Total items: {2}"));
    pager.PageSizes(new int[]{5,10,20,50,100,1000});
    pager.Refresh(true);
})
.ClientRowTemplate("rowtemplate")
)

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="rowtemplate">
    "<tr>" +
        "<td>" +
           "#= FirstName#" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
           "#= LastName#" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
            "#= Age#" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
            "#= Course#" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td>" +
            "#= School.Name#" +
        "</td>" +
     "</tr>" 
</script>
```

What is being shown in the grid is just one row with the id of the template `rowtemplate` (repeated)

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I would like to do something like this: [ClientRowTemplate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452597/possible-to-use-clientrowtemplate-kendo-ui-grid-without-building-a-string), but it seems that is not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for to apply a row template to a grid but make sure that FirstName etc fields are valid.So just remove string here and just write simple HTML.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="rowtemplate">
<tr>
    <td>
       #= FirstName#
    </td>
    <td>
       #= LastName#
    </td>
    <td>
        #= Age#
    </td>
    <td>
        #= Course#
    </td>
    <td>
        #= School.Name#
    </td>
 </tr> 
 </script>
```